# How can I repeat a calculation for a range of columns?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to repeat a formula for a range of columns but currently I have to just repeat it with different column letters

I've tried `COUNTIFS`, `SUMIFS` to repeat them but they don't seem to work in the way I require, I want to avoid repeating the same logic of code for each new column I add

```
=SUM(B6-C6) + (IF($H$3 = A6, (COUNTIF($H$6:$H$21, "Paid") * $H$22)) + IF($I$3 = A6, (COUNTIF($I$6:$I$21, "Paid") * $I$22)) + IF($J$3 = A6, (COUNTIF($J$6:$J$21, "Paid") * $J$22))
```

I wanted to be able to do something along the lines of this(in pseudo code)
`=SUM(B6-C6) + EACHCOLUMN([RANGE], (IF(${{COLUMN}}$3 = A6, (COUNTIF(${{COLUMN}}$6:${{COLUMN}}$21, "Paid") * ${{COLUMN}}$22))`

Comment: Can A6's value happen multiple times or will it always only be one column that needs to be summed?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=B6 - C6 + COUNTIF(INDEX($H$6:$J$21,0,MATCH(A6,$H$3:$J$3,0)),"Paid")*INDEX($H$22:$J$22,0,MATCH(A6,$H$3:$J$3,0))
```